# left and right aligned text inside input element (name: value) + flexible

Tags: javascript, html, css

**What I need:**
I need value name text (align left) and value itself (align right) inside `<input>` element. It must be flexible (input width and height will change)

I worked out static solution involving `<span>` and some css, but it is not flexable. I am **resizing** elements depending on device viewport and that solution is not working for me.

html:

```
<div id="subgroup-input-supply">
  <span>Supply:</span>
  <input id="input-supply" type="text" value="100%" readonly>
</div>
```

css:

```
#subgroup-input-supply span{
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-top: 1px;
}
#input-supply{
  text-align: right;
}
```

[image: What i am trying to do]

[JS Fiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/SavageStyle/cj0sk9xh/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `position:relative` to your parent. That'll keep them in place.

https://jsfiddle.net/cj0sk9xh/2/

Comment: input height can change: https://jsfiddle.net/SavageStyle/cj0sk9xh/4/
- as you can see no longer centered

Answer (score 0):

Position absolute: The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element.

So make its first parent element position `relative`.

```css
#subgroup-input-supply{
  position:relative;
}
#subgroup-input-supply span{
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-top: 1px;
}
#input-supply{
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="subgroup-input-supply">
  <span>Supply:</span>
  <input id="input-supply" type="text" value="100%" readonly>
</div>
```